# Find the radius of convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{n}}{n^{2}{(5+\cos(n\pi/3))^{n}}}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{n}}{n^{2}{(5+\cos(n\pi/3))^{n}}}$$

What is the radius of the convergence of the series?

Please show clearly and help me how to solve this. Thank you!

I know the $R=\dfrac{1}{\limsup|a_n|^{1/n}}$ but I cannot find value of limsup. My actual question to you is this!!?

Comment: Sorry!!! I rewrite the correct form!

Comment: You still have two useless extra parentheses.

Comment: You can show $\limsup\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}|a_n|^{1/n}=\limsup\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}{1\over  5+\cos(n\pi/3) }= $ ?? (what happens for $n$ an odd multiple of $3$?)

Comment: Yes what is the value of the lımsup? Please can you explicitly write below the way of the solution to find the value?  Please! @DavidMitra

Comment: $limsupn→∞|an|^{1/n}=lim supn→∞{n^{2}(5+cos(nπ/3))}$ What is the value of this? @DavidMitra

Comment: See julien's answer.

Comment: @UserN48 Kindly do not deface your question.

Comment: Ok sorry @marvais

Comment: @UserN48 Why would you want to delete it, given that there are two answers and you have accepted one of them? Defacing a question is not encouraged on this site.

Comment: @UserN48 Please do not change the question now that it's been answered and accepted. Why would you want to do that anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So let's try to apply the limsup formula for the radius of convergence, since you say this is your actual question.

First compute
$$
\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}=\frac{1}{n^{2/n}(5+\cos(n\pi/3))}.
$$

Recall that $\limsup x_n$ is the largest $x$ such that there exists a subsequence of $x_n$ converging to $x$.

Note that $n^{2/n}=\exp
(2\log n/n)$ converges to $1$, so that 
$$
\limsup \sqrt[n]{|a_n|}=\limsup \frac{1}{5+\cos(n\pi/3)}.
$$

First oberve that 
$$
\frac{1}{5+\cos(n\pi/3)}\leq \frac{1}{5-1}=\frac{1}{4}
$$
for all $n$. So $\limsup \sqrt[n]{|a_n|}\leq 1/4$.

And now for the extraction $n_k=3(2k+1)$, we have
$$
\frac{1}{5+\cos(n_k\pi/3)}=\frac{1}{4}.
$$
Hence $\limsup \sqrt[n]{|a_n|}\geq 1/4$.

Finally $\limsup \sqrt[n]{|a_n|}= 1/4$ and by the formula for the radius of convergence, $R=4$.

Comment: You're welcome! It took me some time to get it right... but we finally got it.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** OP has changed the question, replacing $n^2$ with $n^{56}$, and $5$ with $23$, and $n\pi/3$ with $n\pi/7$. Fundamentally, nothing changes, the radius of convergence is now $22$, same argument.

**Original Question:** This asked for the radius of convergence of $\displaystyle \sum_1^\infty \frac{x^n}{n^2(5+\sin(n\pi/3))^n}$.

**Answer:** Applying the Ratio Test, or the Root Test, shows that the radius of convergence is $\ge 4$. 
You may want to compare with the simpler series $\displaystyle\sum_1^\infty \frac{x^n}{n^24^n}$.

To show that nothing $\gt 4$ will do, show that if $|x|\gt 4$, then the terms do not have limit $0$.
The issue is that $\cos(n\pi/3)$ is $-1$ for infinitely many $n$.

Comment: Thanks for helping me realize that I had first gone completely wrong...